# How to put an array into a class (C++)

Tags: c++

Hello does anyone of you know how to put an array into a class whenever I put an array into a class it gets "**error: initializer**" I'm using codeblocks btw...

```
    class TVshow {
       private:
                std::string rating;
       public:
    std::string title;
    std::string director;
    std::string valid_rating[] = {"G", "PG", "PG-13", "R", "NR"};
    TVshow(std::string aTitle, std::string aDirector, std::string aRating) {
        title = aTitle;
        director = aDirector;
        setRating(aRating);
    }
    void setRating(std::string aRating) {
        rating = aRating;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide the size.

```cpp
std::string valid_rating[5] = {"G", "PG", "PG-13", "R", "NR"};
```

You can initialize on declaration as it is now or better would be inside a constructor.